# Angular2: Input value stuck and get undefined upon submitting form

Tags: angular, ionic3

Hello I've come accross something I haven't encountered before in angular below is my code:

```
showDirectoryList(){
    const showMyDirectoryList:Modal = 
      this.showContactsModal.create(ModalShowDirectoryPage);

    showMyDirectoryList.present();
    showMyDirectoryList.onDidDismiss((data)=>{
      this.directoryList.push(data);
    });
}
```

This code opens a list modal then gets the id of the selected I was able to do that via `IonDidDimsiss()`. I was even able to have it display in my view but apparently when I do a test submit it comes up empty now I'm wondering why was It empty when clearly I saw items getting pushed into the input textbox.

Here is the html of my code:

```
<ion-navbar color="beacon-green">
    <ion-title>Create A Broadcast</ion-title>
    <button ion-button menuToggle>
        <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
</ion-navbar>
```

```
<ion-content padding>
    <form [formGroup]="sendBroadCastForm" novalidate (ngSubmit) ="send(sendBroadCastForm.value)">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" formControlName="broadcastName" placeholder="Campaign Title"/>
        </div>
        <div class="spacer-10"></div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" formControlName="msisdnList" placeholder="To:"/>
        </div>
        <div class="spacer-10"></div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">           
                <div col-10>
                <input type="text" formControlName="phonebookIds" [(ngModel)]="phonebookIds" placeholder="Directory List" value="{{[directoryList]}}">
                </div>
                <div col-1>
                    <ion-icon name="add-circle" color="beacon-orange" float-right (click)="showDirectoryList()"></ion-icon>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="spacer-10"></div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
                <ion-item>
                    <ion-label>Broadcast Date</ion-label>
                    <ion-datetime displayFormat="YYYY/MM/DD" formControlName="broadcastDate"></ion-datetime>
                </ion-item>
                <div class="spacer-10"></div>
                <ion-item>
                    <ion-label>Broadcast Time</ion-label>
                    <ion-datetime displayFormat="HH:mm:ss" formControlName="broadcastTime"></ion-datetime>
                </ion-item>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="spacer-30"></div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <textarea rows="6" cols="33" formControlName="message"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="spacer-20"></div>
        <p class="draftTime" [hidden]="!autoSaveDetails">Draft saved at: {{autoSaveDetails|date:"mediumTime"}}</p>
        <div class="spacer-30"></div>
        <ion-fab bottom center>

            <button type="submit" ion-fab color="beacon-orange" ><ion-icon name="paper-plane"></ion-icon></button>
        </ion-fab>
    </form>

</ion-content>
```

Im wondering what's causing and if anyone can point me to what I was doing wrong.Thanks.

Comment: Does the error still persist if you place this line `showMyDirectoryList.present();` **after** this one: `showMyDirectoryList.onDidDismiss(.....)`? Presenting the modal should be the last step, after setting the `onDidDismiss` callback.

Comment: Haven't tried yet but what is it supposed to do? i can already open the modal and get the value of list when I click on it, then I hook on to the IonviewDidDismiss lifecycle to pass the data. the problem is its displaying on  the page which is the create campaign but when i submit the form its value is empty my temp solution is to have two events one residing on the component and the other is to show the animation updating the textbox.